# What is CodeResources in Cocoa Mac apps?

Tags: cocoa, macos, resources

I see these `CodeResources` folders in some of the system Mac apps and some third party apps. What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is a result of [code signing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html); it keeps track of the digital signatures of various application resources (images, etc.).